# What is the .bundle file extension in apk?

Tags: android, apk, apktool

I was wondering what the .bundle file extension is when you unzip a apk file.
Are a developer even able to view these files?

Comment: Developers can name their files as they want. So you can name files `.bundle` or whatever you like. The file content can be totally different. Therefore your question can not be answered.